# Tab character in exiftool

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting, special-characters

I need to insert tab character on place of _ between day and hour.

```
exiftool -T -r -filename -CreateDate -d "%Y%"."%m%"."%d_%H%"."%M%"."%S" /Users/***/***/testmapa/mapa2/ > /Users/***/***/testmapa/out10.csv
```

I have tried to insert it in all possible ways with \t, in combination with "",'',& and no collapse. It just wont work for me. Im using osx terminal. Take note that line is in .Command file. Not terminal itself.

Edit; my solution was ## and `| perl -pE 's/##/\t/g'`

Comment: You can try (outside of double quotes) `$'\t'`, or press Ctrl+V followed by the Tab key. (OS X has an older bash than Linuxes, so I'm not entirely sure these will work.)

Comment: I tried that before, it wont work. And I have stated that that line is in .command file, so keyboard shortcuts are not useful.

Comment: In that case can't you just simply insert a literal Tab character in the file?

Comment: Its not working. Tried that too...

Comment: my solution was ## and | perl -pE 's/##/\t/g'

Answer (score 0):

It is still awkward to enter a tab in `Exiftool -p` output. I found that using this approach will insert one:

```
Exiftool -p '$Tag1${Filename;s/.*/\t/}$Tag2' <directory> > outfile.txt
```

Essentially, `${Filename;s/.*/\t/}` takes a "known" valid EXIF Tag (Filename) and substitutes its entire value with just the Tab character, not Filename.

`.*` -   `.` matches any character. `*` means match any number of times.

Note: Single quotes `'` for Mac; double quotes `"` for PC.